# Keeping dot files synched across machines?

Tags: unix, configuration-files

Like most *nix people, I tend to play with my tools and get them configured just the way that I like them. This was all well and good until recently. As I do more and more work, I tend to log onto more and more machines, and have more and more stuff that's configured great on my home machine, but not necessarily on my work machine, or my web server, or any of my work servers...

How do you keep these config files updated? Do you just manually copy them over? Do you have them stored somewhere public?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I've had pretty good luck keeping my files under a revision control system. It's not for everyone, but most programmers should be able to appreciate the benefits. 
Read

> [Keeping Your Life in Subversion](http://www.onlamp.com/pub/a/onlamp/2005/01/06/svn_homedir.html)

for an excellent description, including how to handle non-dotfile configuration (like cron jobs via the [svnfix script](http://git.kitenet.net/?p=joey/home.git;a=blob_plain;f=bin/fixups;hb=HEAD)) on multiple machines.

Answer (score 8):

I also use subversion to manage my dotfiles.  When I login to a box my confs are automagically updated for me.  I also use github to store [my confs](http://github.com/claytron/dotfiles/tree/master) publicly.  I use git-svn to keep the two in sync.

Getting up and running on a new server is just a matter of running a few commands.  The create_links script just creates the symlinks from the .dotfiles folder items into my `$HOME`, and also touches some files that don't need to be checked in.

```
$ cd

# checkout the files
$ svn co https://path/to/my/dotfiles/trunk .dotfiles

# remove any files that might be in the way
$ .dotfiles/create_links.sh unlink

# create the symlinks and other random tasks needed for setup
$ .dotfiles/create_links.sh
```

Answer (score 7):

It seems like everywhere I look these days I find a new thing that makes me say "Hey, that'd be a good thing to use [DropBox](http://www.getdropbox.com/) for"

Answer (score 6):

Rsync is about your best solution. Examples can be found here:

http://troy.jdmz.net/rsync/index.html

Comment: Again, WTF?! Another downvote for mentioning rsync. What do we have, a rsync hater? SO is baffling sometimes. Have some rep.

Comment: I love rsync but it's not very good here.  Suppose you have 5 machines.  With rsync, you have to designate a master and tie the others to it.  If you make changes on two different machines, you can't sync them back to the master without overwriting something.  Rsync has its place but this isn't it.

Comment: I am pondering using rsync in combination with version control. You definitely don't want to do it with just rsync; makes messing things up very very easy (it's what we have version control for).

Comment: It depends on your use case; I think rsync is perfect in some situations. I have dropbox syncing my dotfiles, but want the servers I manage to have the same environment as ex. my laptop. Some of those servers don't have any business even having version control installed, and a script that rsyncs my laptop dotfiles across all my servers is perfect.

Answer (score 6):

I use git for this.

There is a wiki/mailing list dedicated to the topic.

[vcs-home](http://vcs-home.madduck.net/)

Comment: I do it like Daniel Bungert here, and in fact my dotfile repos is visible publicly since I share it with my friends. We pull interesting tricks from each other :)

For those interested, I would be happy to divulge my git web url.

Comment: Same here. Using git. Have one "master" repo on my main working machine. Then one local branch on the master repo for each other machine (or just for different configs). Have one `master` branch to host things visible in all homes. Only very few machine specific workarounds go into the specific branches. No scripts needed. Big documents are not in my home. Projects are not in my home. Separate things/concepts go into separate repos.

Answer (score 5):

I would definetly recommend [homesick](https://github.com/technicalpickles/homesick). It uses git and automatically symlinks your files. `homesick track` tracks a new dotfile, while `homesick symlink` symlinks new dotfiles from the repository into your homefolder. This way you can even have more than one repository.

Comment: I have by the way created my own clone of homesick in bash, because I didn't like the ruby dependency: https://github.com/andsens/homeshick

Answer (score 3):

You could use rsync.  It works through ssh which I've found useful since I only setup new servers with ssh access.

Or, create a tar file that you move around everywhere and unpack.

Comment: WTF? Why did you get -1 for suggesting rsync? Have some rep.

Answer (score 2):

I store them in my version control system.

Answer (score 2):

i use svn ... having a public and a private repository ... so as soon as i get on a server i just

```
svn co http://my.rep/home/public
```

and have all my dot files ...

Answer (score 2):

I store mine in a `git` repository, which allows me to easily merge beyond system dependent changes, yet share changes that I want as well.

Answer (score 1):

I keep master versions of the files under CM control on my main machine, and where I need to, arrange to copy the updates around.  Fortunately, we have NFS mounts for home directories on most of our machines, so I actually don't have to copy all that often.  My profile, on the other hand, is rather complex - and has provision for different PATH settings, etc, on different machines.  Roughly, the machines I have administrative control over tend to have more open source software installed than machines I use occasionally without administrative control.

So, I have a random mix of manual and semi-automatic process.

Answer (score 1):

There is [netskel](http://macnugget.org/projects/netskel/) where you put your common files on a web server, and then the client program maintains the dot-files on any number of client machines. It's designed to run on any level of client machine, so the shell scripts are proper `sh` scripts and have a minimal amount of dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

Svn here, too.  Rsync or unison would be a good idea, except that sometimes stuff stops working and i wonder what was in my .bashrc file last week.  Svn is a life saver in that case.

Answer (score 1):

Now I use [Live Mesh](http://www.mesh.com) which keeps all my files synchronized across multiple machines.

Answer (score 1):

I put all my dotfiles in to a folder on Dropbox and then symlink them to each machine. Changes made on one machine are available to all the others almost immediately. It just works.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your environment you can also use (fully backupped) NFS shares ...

Answer (score 0):

Speaking about storing dot files in public there are

http://www.dotfiles.com/

and

http://dotfiles.org/

But it would be really painful to manually update your files as (AFAIK) none of these services provide any API.

The latter is really minimalistic (no contact form, no information about who made/owns it etc.)

Answer (score 0):

> **[briefcase](https://github.com/jim/briefcase)** is a tool to facilitate keeping dotfiles in git, including those with private information (such as .gitconfig).
>
> By keeping your configuration files in a git public git repository, you can share your settings with others. Any secret information is kept in a single file outside the repository (it’s up to you to backup and transport this file).
>
> -- http://jim.github.com/briefcase

Answer (score 0):

### mackup

https://github.com/lra/mackup

Ira/mackup is a utility for Linux & Mac systems that will sync application preferences using almost any popular shared storage provider (dropbox, icloud, google drive). It works by replacing the dot files with symlinks.

It also has a large library of hundreds of applications that are supported https://github.com/lra/mackup/tree/master/mackup/applications